# Denoising an image channel with sliding DCT algorithm

Tags: matlab, dct

I am trying to build a function that denoises every channel of an image using DCT, and outputs the clean channel. My function so far:

```
function denoised_ch = sliding_dct(channel, variance)
% choose window size as 8x8
fun1 = @(block_struct) dct2(block_struct.data(:));
dct_ch = blockproc(channel, [8 8], fun1);
[r, c] = size(dct_ch);
% threshold the DCT coeff with threshold = 3xvariance of the channel
fun2 = @(block_struct) idct2(block_struct.data(:));
denoised_ch = blockproc(channel, [8 8], fun2);
```

How can I implemement the part about thresholding? (The commented part)

Comment: `std()` gives you the standard deviation of an array. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No, but I am looking to threshold the values of the channel that are more than 3x the channel's variance, and perform idct2 on the remaining values in the channel.

Comment: Well, then use the standard deviation, square it, multiply it by three and use a logical test.

Comment: I have the variance already calculated. Could you help me with the logical test part?

Comment: I assume you want to apply the threshold to `dct_ch` variable. You could try something like `idx = dct_ch > 3*variance`. This `idx` variable is a logical array which 1s are values in `dct_ch` greater than 3 times the variance. As @Adriaan said. The rest is up to you. If you want to delete these values greater than, you can write `dct_ch (idx) = []`; if you want to alter them, just assign the value you want, mean, median, etc. As `dct_ch (idx)`, *idx* says to *dct_ch* array which values use.